# Where is the source code for the modified Linux kernel used by Roku?

Tags: linux-kernel, licensing, roku

Roku ships with a modified version of the Linux kernel.

The Linux kernel is protected by the [GNU GPL version 2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html).

That license requires every user receive at-cost access to the source code of those changes, but I cannot find a repo with those modifications.

Comment: Googling for "roku gpl" leads you to here: https://www.roku.com/separatelylicensedcode

Comment: Yes, but there is only patches to a few Ring3 apps, nothing for Ring0.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if it only shows-up if you login.  I do not have an account.

Comment: Since my answer was deleted (wow, 4 years ago), I will include the link here since it is still working: https://roku.app.box.com/v/RokuOpenSourceSoftware